# Jenkins not running on scheduled time

Tags: selenium, jenkins, job-scheduling

I have 3 build to run on every day on specific time, I have scheduled them @19:00, @21:00 & @23:00 with 2hrs gap on each build, after office timing I have left my system on sleep mode. but everyday it is starting on 12:00 AM, also among 40 case, only 2-3 cases are ran and remaining cases are start running when I login to my system.
Any help, why is this happening.
I want my cases to be run in every night. so I can get the result in the morning.

Jenkin showing this message on scheduling.

Would last have run at Wednesday, August 25, 2021 7:56:27 PM IST; would next run at Thursday, August 26, 2021 7:56:27 PM IST.

& this is the result when yesterday it has ran,

C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\Com>java org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\Com\TestNG.xml
**Aug 26, 2021 12:03:21 AM** org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.43 (8c61b7e2989f2990d42f859cac71319137787cce-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#306}) on port 37985
Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: where is your jenkins hosted? is it local?

Comment: Yes, it is hosted on my local.